# Is there any limits for using Google map for android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

i am using google map for a simple android application that load the map to save positions on database and show them later on the map by markers. so i wonder if there is a limitation or is it completely free ?

i am using a mapView

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

and

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
```

i was looking on the google map documentaion but i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google gives you $200 service every month free.after that you will be charged. (but some features absolute free for mobile like static,dynamic map)
more info [Google map pricing](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing)
[image: prices on 2020-April]